# Orbits of $f(z) = 2z^3+z.$

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $f(z) = 2z^3+z.$ What are the values of $z$ such that $z, f(z), f(f(z)), \dots$ is eventually periodic? I'm asking because I wish to classify all monic polynomials $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $p(z)|p(f(z)).$ If $S$ is the set of roots of $p,$ then we derive $r \in S \Rightarrow f(r) \in S,$ which eliminates the possibility of any roots that do not eventually lead to cycles.

Unfortunately, $0, f^{-1}(0) = \{0, \pm i/\sqrt{2}\}, f^{-2}(0), \dots$ all work. However, it would help to know that there are no other examples. Is this true?

Comment: All complex polynomials of degree at least 2 have a non-trivial (in fact highly complicated) "Julia set"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set . Periodic orbits are countable (not finite) and dense in the Julia set. If I have understood your idea correctly, I don't think it may lead you very far?

Comment: What do you mean by "values of $z$"? Complex values? Real values? Rational values? As has already been said, the complex values that are periodic are dense in the very complicated Julia set. And you're even asking about preperiodic values, which are values with finite forward orbit. Those are in the Julia set, too, and there are even more of those. On the other hand, there are only finitely many preperiodic $z$ values in any given number field (finite extension of $\mathbb Q$). That's a very special case of a famous theorem of Northcott.